# rename a column in a list of dataframes in using purrr::walk

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I need to rename the second columns for all the dataframes in a list. I'm trying to use purrr::walk.

Here is the code:

```
cyl.name<- c('4-cyl', '6-cyl', '8-cyl')
cyl<- c(4,6,8)    
car <- map(cyl, ~mtcars %>% filter(cyl==.x) %>%
                     group_by(gear) %>% 
                     summarise(mean=mean(hp)) )
walk (seq_along(cyl.name), function (x) names(car[[x]])[2]<- cyl.name[x])
```

When I check the columns names, all the mean column are still named 'mean'. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You're making your data structure more complicated and untidy than it needs to be; all you need is `mtcars %>% 
        group_by(gear, cyl) %>% 
        summarise(mean = mean(hp))`

Answer (score 4):

If you have the list of the column names like this, you could use `map2` to simultaneously loop through the `filter` variable and the naming variable.  This would allow you to name the columns as you go rather than renaming after making the list.

This does involve using some `tidyeval` operations from *rlang* for [programming with *dplyr*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).

```
map2(cyl, cyl.name, ~mtcars %>% 
         filter(cyl==.x) %>%
         group_by(gear) %>%
         summarise( !!.y := mean(hp)) )

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   gear `4-cyl`
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     3      97
2     4      76
3     5     102

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
   gear `6-cyl`
  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     3   107.5
2     4   116.5
3     5   175.0

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   gear  `8-cyl`
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     3 194.1667
2     5 299.5000
```